# Is it possible in C++ to define several methods at once?

Tags: c++, meta-programming

Sorry for the confusing title of this question, but I can't think of an exact way to word it. I have a very long class with hundreds of similar methods and I am trying to find a way to construct it without so many lines of code and so many DRY violations. Each time I add a new property to my class I have to write two methods and update the copy function. There are already over 80 properties.

Currently this class is written in Java but I was wondering if it were written in C++ if it could be done more efficiently. I think it can be done using preprocessor x-macros [like described in wikipedia here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) but I am not a fan of macros and would prefer to do it using the language itself if possible.

Here is a simplified snippet of my Java class:

```
class InMemoryPerson implements Person {
    private HashMap<String,Object> values = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    public InMemoryPerson copyFrom(Person p) {
        setName(p.getName());
        // more code to copy all the properties...
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        values.put("name",name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return (String)map.get("name");
    }

    // many more methods for all the different properties...
    // each method may have a different type
}
```

Comment: You might want to rethink your design completely. 80 member variables that all need accessors _sounds_ wrong.

Comment: There is only one member variable, the HashMap :). It sounds wrong, but for other engineers who use this class it is very useful to have access to all this data in a single object.

Comment: Then what do you need 80 methods for?

Comment: Don't worry about a bit of DRY violation when you're doing three truckloads of SRP violations (you are, no sane single-responsibility class would have 80 properties).

Comment: The need for updating the copy function can be avoided by using default copy ctors, as @BЈовић has pointed out. For getters and setters, however, I would bite the bullet and use macros.

Comment: maybe you need this http://steve-yegge.blogspot.ca/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html

Comment: Is C++ your only option? C# allows `string Name { get; set; }` which automatically a basic getter/setter; for what you have there you can use the `value` keyword and a little shorthand. Check the [MSDN docs on Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: @MadKeithV - Describing a person seems like a single responsibility to me and if you really can't think of 80 details that might vary from person to person I'd call that failure of imagination. Of course there *might* be reason to separate those details into several classes for aspects of the person, but if there's no good reason to do that in the application that's just a pointless abstraction overhead. Just to be clear, I mean overhead in the code complexity sense, not the performance sense.

Comment: @MadKeithV - basically, no design principle can be reliably defined by numeric limits. A single responsibility is a single responsibility, not some maximum number of properties.

Comment: @Steve314 - by the same logic describing the universe is a single responsibility too.

Comment: @jk.: That link deserves at least +1000. And should probably be given as answer with a hint what it means for this particular case.

Comment: @MadKeithV - no, that's a strawman you're fighting there. I said that you don't subdivide a class just to achieve some arbitrary numeric size limit. That doesn't mean the goal is to build huge classes as you're trying to imply. Having one class to hold some person-related properties and another class to hold some more person-related properties and another class to hold ... purely because there's a lot of properties isn't what "single responsibility" is about is all.

Comment: @MadKeithV - there's a related thing in databases. You certainly subdivide database records into smaller records to achieve certain design goals - the normal principles for this are called [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). But you don't subdivide just because you've reached some size limit - it's perfectly valid to have a lot of fields in a record. So - imagine that "InMemoryPerson" class is basically the in-memory representation of a database record. Personally, I think that's pretty likely given the name, don't you?

Comment: @Steve314 - If this was an in-memory object for a database record it could and should be generated by a code generator. Doing this by hand for 80+ properties is too error prone.

Comment: @MadKeithV - "should" I agree with, but we don't know about "could". The thing about a stack overflow question is we *don't know* everything about the project. That's a reason why I should be less judgemental about things other than what OP asks. Errrm, did I just say "I", errr - OK, clearly this is all Freuds fault.

Comment: @steve314 :) - yeah it would be more productive if Satur9nine could refute every single assumption.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++ this is possible to do, using old style C macros.

```
// method is get/set method suffix
// name is the key in hash table
#define POINTER_PROPERTY(type,method,name) \
        type get##method(){return (type)_pointer_map[name];} \
        void set##method(type value){_pointer_map[name]=value;}

class InMemoryPerson : Person {
public:
    POINTER_PROPERTY(char *,Name,"name")

private:
    std::map<const char *,void *> _pointer_map;
};
```

Value types would have to be handled by different macro and (easiest way) by different hash for each type. Not sure though this code is more readable and manageable than 80 different get/set functions.

Comment: That is exactly the kind of solution I had in mind. And I believe this *is* easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ it should be quite simple. Throw out setters and getters, and member variables, and use default copy constructors to copy objects of this class. Something like this :

```
struct Person
{
    Person() : name("default name")
    {}

    std::string name;
    // etc
};

Person a;
// set fields of person a
Person b;
// set fields of person b
b = a;
```

Comment: Because I am implementing an interface this is not possible, there are several other implementations and my class must be compatible with the interface. Also there is value to storing this data in a HashMap so I need to keep that as well.

Comment: @satur9nine: C++ and Java are sufficiently different that transliterating your Java class to C++ will not give satisfactory results. There is no free lunch here.

Comment: @satur9nine So, your interface has 180 methods? :) Sorry for laughing, but I find it quite amusing.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: I think you are missing the point, the current Java solution is not satisfactory, and Java and C++ are sufficiently similar that the direct C++ transliterated version of this code won't be satisfactory, too. However, I think I would use macros for this case.

Comment: @DocBrown: I don't think I entirely missed the point. There are multiple ways to look at it. Given the constraints mentioned in the comment, I don't think there is a satisfactory solution in either Java or C++, partially for the same reasons partially for different reasons.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: alas, I think I should have choosen my words more carefully, I think we are on the same track.

Comment: @DocBrown: No offence taken. You made a good point.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer because of the following constraint from a comment...

> Because I am implementing an interface this is not possible, there are several other implementations and my class must be compatible with the interface.

However, it might be an answer for someone else, so...

One option is to provide one getter and setter for each type and to use a parameter to identify which property. I can think of two ways to handle this...

- Use an enumerate to provide all your property names, and store those properties in an array.
- Use a separate struct to define all the member data, possibly as a public member of your class. Store the properties using in a private instance of that struct inside your class. Pass [member pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member) to your getters and setters to identify the property.

Either way allows the getters and setters to handle particular properties specially if needed. The member pointer method is only really mentioned for completeness, though - I'd prefer the enumerate method.

Once you can identify which property using a parameter, you still need different getters and setters for each property datatype. This can be avoided by specifying your getter and setter as member template functions. You still need some checks, though, to ensure that the property for the current call has the correct type. This is actually easier if you used the member pointer approach (the template can require that the member type for the member pointer matches the get/set type) though you'll probably get other problems later.

The most obvious case where something like this is justified is if you're developing a RAD-style tool.

Answer (score 0):

The need for updating the copy function can be avoided by using default copy ctors, as @BЈовић has pointed out. For getters and setters, however, I would bite the bullet and use X-macros (if you don't want to write an external code generator for this).

Whatever you do, you need a place where you associate the hash key `"name"` with the associated data type `String` and the corresponding getter/setter names (the names of these methods may follow a strict convention, but AFAIK there is no easy uppercase/lowercase conversion within the preprocessor). So defining that list using X-macros will at least give you a very compact and easy-to-extend solution (EDIT: see @petrch's post for an example).

Answer (score 0):

There was a three-part series on Embedded.com about X-macros, that gives a cleaner result than what the Wikipedia article describes.

```
#define EXPAND_AS_ENUMERATION(a,b) a,
#define EXPAND_AS_JUMPTABLE(a,b) b, 
#define STATE_TABLE(ENTRY)     \
        ENTRY(STATE_0, func_0) \
        ENTRY(STATE_1, func_1) \
        ENTRY(STATE_2, func_2) \
        ...                    \
        ENTRY(STATE_X, func_X)

/* declare an enumeration of state codes */ 
enum{
    STATE_TABLE(EXPAND_AS_ENUMERATION)
    NUM_STATES
}

/* declare a table of function pointers */ 
p_func_t jumptable[NUM_STATES] = {
    STATE_TABLE(EXPAND_AS_JUMPTABLE)
}:
```

Here's [Part 1](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4403953/C-language-coding-errors-with-X-macros-Part-1).

Here's [Part 2](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4405283/Reduce-C--language-coding-errors-with-X-macros---Part-2).

They blew the in-article link to Part 3.  [Here](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4408127/Reduce-C-language-coding-errors-with-X-macros--Part-3) it is.

They require you to create a free account and profile, so they can spam you, if you want to read more than 2 articles per day.  (BOO!  HISS!)  The 2-article limit is a fairly recent change to what used to be a really good site.